# How to store values of a particular line of a text file in separate variables in Python

Tags: python

I have a text file , which reads this.

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h    
a,b,c,i,j,k,l,m    
f,k
```

Now, I want to store the first line as a list, second list in other list. But the third two values, I want to store in some particular variables say a=f, b=k.

I have made the code, but its showing error during reading the third line.
Please someone help this.

Here is my code.

```
filename = 'input.txt'     
fin=open(filename,'r')    
n=fin.readline()    
m=fin.readline()    
a,b=fin.readline()
```

UPDATE:

```
with open('input.txt') as fin:
    n=fin.readline().split()
    m=fin.readline().split()

    line=(fin.readline())

a,b=line[0],line[2]

i=0

for i in range(0,len(n)): 
    if n[i]!=a:
        i+=1
    cp=i-1

i=0
for i in range(0,len(n)): 
    if n[i]!=a:
        i+=1
    posa=i-1

i=0
for i in range(0,len(n)): 
    if m[i]!=b:
        i+=1
    posb=i-1

while(posa>cp):
    posa-=1

while(posa>cp):
    posb-=1

if(cp<0):
    print("No Common Predecessor")

elif (posa<posb):
    if(posa<0):
        posa=0
    print("Common Predecessor: %s" %n[posa])

else:
    if(posb<0):
        posb=0
    print("Common Predecessor: %s" %m[posb])
```

Comment: `a,b=fin.readline().split()` ... not even worth posting as an answer ...

Comment: @Joran: `split()` by itself doesn't split on commas.

Comment: ahhh dang ... my smartassery bites me in the keister again

Comment: What, if anything, does the extra code-dump have to do with your question?

Answer (score 4):

Method `readline()` returns string. To get a list you have to use:

```
m=fin.readline().strip().split(',')
n=fin.readline().strip().split(',')
a,b=fin.readline().strip().split(',')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use with open;

```
with open('my.txt') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
    # lines[0] == 'a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h'
    # lines[1] == 'a,b,c,i,j,k,l,m' 
    # lines[2] == 'f,k'
    # lines[3] == '.'

    n = list(lines[0].split(','))
    m = list(lines[1].split(','))
    a, b = lines[2].split(',')

    # n == ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h    ']
    # m == ['a', 'b', 'c', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm    ']
    # a == f
    # b == k
```

Then you can do what you want with each line.

Comment: That means, f and k will be stored in the same variable ,lines[2]. 
I want to store it in two different variable, say a and b.

Comment: @DipayanDev I haven't declared any variables there, I've just shown what each part of `lines` looks like hence the `==`. You can declare your variables from `lines`, like `a, b = lines[2].split(',')`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies with the fact that `a,b=fin.readline()` would execute `fin.readline()` twice, giving you `a = 'f,k'` and `b = '.'` (which is the following line that is read)

To prevent this, you could assign the previous line to a variable and *then* split it into variables `a` and `b`.

For example:

```
filename = 'input.txt'    
fin = open(filename )
n=fin.readline().split()
m=fin.readline().split()
line=(fin.readline())
a,b=line.split(',')
b=b.strip()
```

Or a more simplified approach using `with open`:

```
with open('input.txt') as fin:
    n=fin.readline().split()
    m=fin.readline().split()
    line=(fin.readline())
    a,b=line.split(',')
    b=b.strip()
```

Both of these approches would yield the output:

```
>>> n
['a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h']

>>> m
['a,b,c,i,j,k,l,m']

>>> a
'f'

>>> b
'k'
```

Comment: I tried your solution. It shows error when I am trying to access 'a' in the later program. 
IndexError: List index out of range ( at 'a')

Comment: @DipayanDev That would depend how you're calling `a` later on in the program. Either edit that into your question or ask a new question for that problem. Preferably the latter.

Comment: @DipayanDev I made an edit to my code, try it now. Let me know if it works.

Comment: with open('input.txt') as fin:
    n=fin.readline().split()
    m=fin.readline().split()
    line=(fin.readline())
    a,b=line[0],line[2]
    print (a) 
    print (b)
    print (n)
i=0
while(n[i]==m[i]):
    i+=1
cp=i-1
i=0
while(n[i]!=a):
    i+=1
posa=i-1
i=0
while(m[i]!=b):
    i+=1
posb=i-1
while(posa>cp):
    posa-=1
while(posa>cp):
    posb-=1

if(cp<0):
    print("No Common Predecessor")
elif (posa<posb):
    if(posa<0):
        posa=0
    print("Common Predecessor: %s" %n[posa])
else:
    if(posb<0):
        posb=0
    print("Common Predecessor: %s" %m[posb])

Comment: @DipayanDev you can't paste code into the comments like that, try "editing" it into your question instead

Comment: @DipayanDev Instead of using a while-loop, use a for-loop. For example, `for i in range(0,len(n)): if n[i]!=a:` ... same thing with the next while. Replace them with a for loop and an if statement. This is because you increment `i` past the number of elements in the lists `n` and `m`

Comment: Edited the question again with for loop. 
Same error showing in if n[i]!=a.

Comment: @DipayanDev Accept an answer for this question and post a new question. Because the question you have now is not relevant to the one that was asked earlier.