# How to redirect the output of print statement of (if-else) to a text file in Python

Tags: python, redirect, python-3.x, python-3.5

I have this piece of code, and print the output to a txt file. 
However whenever I open a file, 
f=open("out.txt",'w') it shows unexpected indent. I guess I am placing the line of code to a wrong position.
Can anyone help.

```
if(cp<0):

    print("No Common Predecessor")
elif (posa < posb):

    if(posa<0):
        posa=0
    print("Common Predecessor: %s" %n[posa])
else:

    if(posb < 0):
        posb=0
    print("Common Predecessor: %s" %m[posb])
```

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Comment: Hi, I am using python 3.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python3 the output redirection is as simple as

```
print(....., file = open("filename",'w'))
```

Refer the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print)

In your particular case you can even use the `with open` syntax as in

```
if(cp<0):

    print("No Common Predecessor")
elif (posa < posb):

    if(posa<0):
        posa=0
    with open('out.txt','w')as f:
        print("Common Predecessor: %s" %n[posa])
        f.write("Common Predecessor: %s" %n[posa])
else:

    if(posb < 0):
        posb=0
    with open('anotherout.txt','w')as f:
        print("Common Predecessor: %s" %m[posb])
        f.write("Common Predecessor: %s" %m[posb])
```

Note - It is always better to use `'a'` (append) instead of `'w'` incase you are re-executing the program.

Comment: print("Common Predecessor: %s" %n[posa],file="out.txt")

Do I need to write this?
getting this error.
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'

Comment: Do I need to add anything?

Comment: Thank a lot . That worked. 
One other solution just found,

Just adding these two lines at the top of the code, leaving the rest same. Will also work.

`import sys

`sys.stdout = open('out.txt', 'w')

Comment: Sure. Thank. Will take you answer.
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29398373/how-to-store-values-of-a-particular-line-of-a-text-file-in-separate-variables-in/29398803?iemail=1&noredirect=1#29398803

Can you just help in this post too.

Comment: No I did not no the answer that is why I did not answer

Comment: Accepted! Done and dusted. :)

Comment: Thanks! You can even upvote answers to show that you liked them. But that is left to your choice

Comment: @BhargavRao While `'a'` is often better than `'w'`, it is best to avoid sweeping generalizations. Sometimes `'w'` is the correct answer.

Comment: @BobChao87 That's why I added it as a sub note!

Comment: @BobChao87 Can you tell me, how to read comma separated txt file?

Comment: @DipayanDev That is a different question. It is better to ask a separate question. That is because you will find better answerers and get very good answers